# Having trouble changing settings on Donations Page

Tags: contribution-page, price-sets, donations

I need to change a checkbox on the Donations page to a box where people can put their own dollar amount in and it will be added to the total at the bottom of the screen. I cannot locate where to go to make that change.

Answer (score 3):

On Amount tab of contribution page (**Contributions menu > Manage Contribution Pages**, then click **Configure** next to the page in question) you can either choose price set or other amount section to have text field where people can input there own amount.

See :
https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/contributions/online-contributions/#amounts-tab

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/events/complex-event-fees/#price-sets

**Price set:**
You can create a price set as text field with amount set to 1 and include the price set in contribution page

OR

**Other amount:**
On amount tab of contribution page you can choose other amount option and choose if you want donor to donate minimum to maximum X amount.(can leave blank if dont need the restriction)